# How to match sed pattern with :

Tags: sed

I have following log:

```
File Process Start : 2014-03-12 - 10:43:40
UnZipping File : fetch_export?id=t63184&file=4
Extracted File : exp_4.mbx
Expected Messages : 6236
File Process Start : 2014-03-12 - 10:57:38
UnZipping File : fetch_export?id=t63185&file=39
Extracted File : 
Expected Messages : 0
File Process Start : 2014-03-12 - 10:57:38
UnZipping File : fetch_export?id=t63185&file=33
Extracted File : 
Expected Messages : 0
File Process Start : 2014-03-12 - 10:57:38
UnZipping File : fetch_export?id=sept2012&file=61
Extracted File : exp_61.mbx
Expected Messages : 7935
```

What i need to change in this command?

```
sed -n  '/File Process Start/,/Expected Messages/p'
```

I need output only between

```
File Process Start
...
Expected Messages : 0
```

Like this:

```
File Process Start : 2014-03-12 - 10:57:38
UnZipping File : fetch_export?id=t63185&file=39
Extracted File : 
Expected Messages : 0
File Process Start : 2014-03-12 - 10:57:38
UnZipping File : fetch_export?id=t63185&file=33
Extracted File : 
Expected Messages : 0
```

Comment: Do you have any condition/checking for getting this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to print the lines between "*File Process Start...*" and "*Expected Messages : 0*". The issue is that you don't know beforehand if you will find the "*Expected Messages : 0*" or "*Expected Messages : X*". So, starting at the "*File Process Start*", keep saving the lines in the hold space until you are able to decide if you will print them or discard them.

```
sed -n '/Expected Messages : 0/{H;g;p};/.*/H;/File Process Start/h' log.txt
```

The pseudocode is:

- If the line contains "*Expected Messages : 0*", (**h**) append this line in the hold space (at this point, the hold space will have the lines "*File Process Start ...*", "*UnZipping File...*" and "*Extracted File...*"), (**g**) get the content from the hold space to the pattern space (i.e. the lines from "*File Process Start...*" until the last one you just appended), (**p**) print the content of the pattern space.
- If the line contains anything else, (**H**) append it to the hold space.
- If the line contains "*File Process Start*", (**h**) wipe out what's in the hold space and put this new line there.

Comment: Great! Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/File Process Start/{h;d};H;/Expected Messages : 0/{g;p}' file
```